# CSV: Strange characters in text data

Tags: csv

I exported a bunch of tweets as a CSV file using a popular tool. However, when I opened the exported data in TextWrangler (and later Microsoft Excel), I see that it contains some strange characters like these, sprinkled between regular text:

```
_Ÿ˜ç_Ÿ_¶
_Ÿ˜ƒ_Ÿ˜ƒ_Ÿ˜ƒ_Ÿ˜ƒ
```

Any idea what these are? I cannot figure a way out for removing them using sed. (Using Mac)

Comment: They are most likely tweets in another language, using a different charset. Try changing the encoding option in your editor, they should eventually start making sense. Also take a look at the Twitter API to see how they encode their replies.

Answer (score 0):

As noted above:

> They are most likely tweets in another language, using a different charset. Try changing the encoding option in your editor, they should eventually start making sense. Also take a look at the Twitter API to see how they encode their replies.